# Need to uninstall rake 0.9.2.2 and install rake 0.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I built a new clean VM, install rvm, and installed ruby  1.9.2 and ran `gem install rails --version '=3.0.7'`.  So far so good.  When I did gem list rake, I saw that rake 0.9.2.2 was installed and I need rake 0.8.7.  I read up on uninstalling rake. Then installed `gem install rake -v='0.8.7'`. This is what I did and observed:

```
gem list rake
  rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
gem uninstall rake 0.9.2.2
  You have requested to uninstall the gem rake-0.8.7
  .......
  Continue [Yn]
  Successfully unistalled rake 0.8.7
  INFO: gem "0.9.2.2" is not installed

gem list rake
  rake (0.9.2.2)
```

Ok so it shows both versons of rake installed at first, I specify to delete 0.9.2.2 and it says its uninstalling 0.8.7 and that it completed uninstalling 0.8.7.  (Not what I entered)  At the end it shows 0.9.2.2 still installed in gem list rake.  I have gone through this iteration multiple times, same result every time.

In the end, I need Ruby 1.9.2; rails 3.0.7 and rake 0.8.7.  The first two I have fine.  But how do I get rake back to 0.8.7?  Or is what I see just some trash left over in some inventory of gems and does not reflect reality?  or can you be sure what you really have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the following command

```
rvm use @global && gem uninstall rake
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue with the predefined constatnts 'Ruby' & 'LN_SUPPORTED'.

However; my 'gem list' only was showing rake 0.9.2.2. So after I was able to install 0.8.7, everything started working again.

```
sudo gem install rake -v=0.8.7
```

Can you do a: `sudo gem uninstall Rake` without specifying a version to get rid of rake completely before trying to reinstall both versions? Or possibly (I know it's frowned upon, but... ) remove the rake gem folder?

Also, maybe you could add `rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)` to your gemfile and then do a `bundle update`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`gem uninstall rake --version 0.9.2.2`